# What could be causing a dripping noise in the ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, noise

There is a dripping noise coming from the vent in the ceiling, but no drip has been detected.  It comes and goes.  We are still using air conditioning in Louisiana.  Could it be the result of cycling with the ac unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could also be water entering the condensation drain line. In many systems there's an air gap at this point, and if this is at the main trunk line, the sound can be transmitted all along the trunk.

I had this exact same thing happen.. I ended up tying a string around the outlet into the drain so that water had a path to the drain that didn't involve a super-loud PLOP! :)

Answer (score 2):

You sure it's a drip and not just the ducts popping from expansion and contraction? Post a video with sound. Generally one doesn't start opening walls until a leak is confirmed. Apply presser to the register when it's making this noise, if it stops it is **just your ducts popping**. To high of a velocity across the coil could carry water into the ductwork, but this probably isn't your problem if the offending register is any great amount of distance from the unit.